# Can I iteratively renew a list of commands? Can I do it with \only in a beamer?

Tags: loops

I would like to make a bunch of copies of a table, each with different subsets of their entries highlighted. After much browsing, I found how to define a `xforeach` command, and managed to create the following partial solution, ilustrated by a sort-of-minimal example.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\newcommand{\A }{A   }
\newcommand{\B }{Beta}
\newcommand{\C }{Ceta}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xforeach}{s m +m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \clist_map_inline:on { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn { o }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\xforeach{A,B}{
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#1\endcsname{ {\color{red} #1}}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c}
  \A  & \B  & \C \\ 
  \A  & \C  & \B \\
  \C  & \B  & \A \\  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

(To be honest, I don't understand very well what happens in the span of `\ExplSyntaxOn`-`\ExplSyntaxOff`)

This gives me two tables, and the right entries are coloured red, but in the second table a B replaces the hoped-for Beta. I understand that there should somehow be a `\` inserted before the `#` `{\color{red} #1}`, but I can't figure out how to do this in a way that compiles.

As my real table is quite large, the highlighting in the entries should be switched on and off, and as I need a many copies of it, I would ideally like to write something like

```
\only<2>{
  \xforeach{A,B}{
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#1\endcsname{ {\color{red} #1}}
    }
```

to indicate that the commands should only be renewed in some subframes.

I really just want a series of tables, not necessarily in Beamer. I mainly use it hoping the business with `\only` will work.

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `xforeach` loop, the `#1` in the redefined macro is merely the letters A and B, not the macros `\A` and `\B`.  The first fix that might occur to you would be to change the `#1` in the redefinition to `\csname#1\endcsname` (this is equivalent to your *suggestion* of `\#1`, which is not valid syntax).  However, even with the valid `\csname` syntax, this would introduce a problem of self reference, akin to the error

```
\def\A{new\A}
```

The solution is to save the existing definitions to a different macro name, and then have the original macros redefined in terms of the saved definitions.  In simple terms,

```
\let\Asv\A
\def\A{new\Asv}
```

So now, in the `\xforeach` loop, I save a copy of `\A` into `\Asv` and `\B` into `\Bsv`.  Then, I redefine `\A` and `\B` in terms of `\Asv` and `\Bsv`, respectively.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\newcommand{\A }{A   }
\newcommand{\B }{Beta}
\newcommand{\C }{Ceta}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xforeach}{s m +m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \clist_map_inline:on { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn { o }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\xforeach{A,B}{
  \expandafter\let\csname#1sv\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname#1\endcsname  
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#1\endcsname{ {\color{red} 
    \csname#1sv\endcsname}}
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c c}
  \A  & \B  & \C \\ 
  \A  & \C  & \B \\
  \C  & \B  & \A \\  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]